# Multi Line Chart.js with two Y-Axes

Tags: javascript, flask, chart.js, flask-sqlalchemy

**Hello everyone,**

I have multiple sensors that measures temperature and humidity. For every sensor i display a chart.js graph on a webserver within every graph two lines: temperature and humidity. For these data I want every line it's own y-axis. I tried to replicate the example of [Line Chart Multiple Axes](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html) of Chart.js

But it won't work. If I look at the source code I see this error message:

```
Chart.bundle.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBasePixel' of undefined
    at i.updateElement (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at i.update (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at i.reset (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at Chart.bundle.min.js:10
    at Object.each (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at t.update (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at t.construct (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at new t (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at buildChart (sensorlog:116)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (sensorlog:163)
updateElement @ Chart.bundle.min.js:10
update @ Chart.bundle.min.js:10
reset @ Chart.bundle.min.js:10
(anonymous) @ Chart.bundle.min.js:10
each @ Chart.bundle.min.js:10
update @ Chart.bundle.min.js:10
construct @ Chart.bundle.min.js:10
t @ Chart.bundle.min.js:10
buildChart @ sensorlog:116
(anonymous) @ sensorlog:163
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
K @ jquery.min.js:2
```

I don't know if I made a typo or an indentation error, or that there is something wrong in my code. Hopefully someone can help me out, thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
{% block tail %}
    <script src="/static/js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function buildChart(id, labels, humidity, temperature) {
            var ctx = $(id).get(0).getContext('2d');
            var dhtChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "Temperature (°C)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)",
                            fillColor: "rgba(225, 225, 0, 1)",
                            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointColor: "rgba(225, 225, 0, 1)",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
                            data: temperature
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Humidity (%)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(0, 128, 255, 1)",
                            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
                            data: humidity
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxis: [{
                                id: 'y-axis-1',                             
                                type: 'linear',
                                position: 'left',
                            }, {
                                id: 'y-axis-2',                             
                                type: 'linear',
                                position: 'right',
                            }]
                        }   
                    }
                });
            }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            {% for sensor in sensors %}
                buildChart('#sensor_chart_{{ sensor.id }}', ["{{ readings|join('\",\"', attribute='time')|safe }}"], [{{ readings|join(',', attribute='hum_value') }}], [{{ readings|join(',', attribute='temp_value') }}]);
            {% endfor %}
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong option format Chart.js
. You must change

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxis: []
    }   
}
```

to

```
options: {
   scales: {
      yAxes: []
   }   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: @ Duc Nguyen Thanks for your comment. It was just a typo, miss that completely. Now it works!